# Extract data from XML (CLOB Type)

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, select, soap

I need to extract data of the `BATCH_ID` from the table `FND_SOA_BODY_PIECE` and Column BODY (datatype: CLOB) which has XML data in it

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>        
      <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <tns1:InputParameters xmlns:tns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/gl/soaprovider/plsql/geas_gl_journal_pkg/geas_get_gl_data/">
                  <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL>
                         <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85380</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                         </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                         <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85345</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                         </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                         <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85364</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                         </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                         <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85356</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                         </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                         <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85374</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                         </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                         <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85358</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                         </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                  </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL>
            </tns1:InputParameters>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I tried this below but it just gave me null values

```
    SELECT xmltype(fsa.body).EXTRACT('/Envelope/Body/InputParameters/P_BATCH_TBL/P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM/BATCH_ID').getStringVal() FROM fnd_soa_body_piece;
```

Could someone help on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, please post valid XML, as what you show looks like a screen scrape from a browser, and is missing the ending  tag and had invalid characters.  If your xml has namespace references, then you need to include them in the XPath and as a parameter to the extract() function.  Here is an example:

```
with fnd_soa_body_piece as (
select xmltype(
      '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
           xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <tns1:InputParameters xmlns:tns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/gl/soaprovider/plsql/geas_gl_journal_pkg/geas_get_gl_data/">
                  <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL>
                        <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85380</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                         </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                        <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85345</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                        </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                        <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85364</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                        </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                        <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85356</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                        </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                        <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85374</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                        </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                        <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85358</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                        </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                  </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL>
            </tns1:InputParameters>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>') body from dual
    )
    select extract(body,'/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Header/SOAP-ENV:Body/tns1:InputParameters/tns1:P_BATCH_TBL/tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM/tns1:BATCH_ID',
    '  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
       xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
       xmlns:tns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/gl/soaprovider/plsql/geas_gl_journal_pkg/geas_get_gl_data/"').getStringVal()
  from fnd_soa_body_piece
```

Update:

To return results as a SQL row set, you need to use the XMLTABLE function, such as:

```
with fnd_soa_body_piece as (
select xmltype(
      '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
      <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
           xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <tns1:InputParameters xmlns:tns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/gl/soaprovider/plsql/geas_gl_journal_pkg/geas_get_gl_data/">
                  <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL>
                        <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85380</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                         </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                        <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85345</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                        </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                        <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85364</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                        </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                        <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85356</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                        </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                        <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85374</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                        </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                        <tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                              <tns1:BATCH_ID>85358</tns1:BATCH_ID>
                        </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM>
                  </tns1:P_BATCH_TBL>
            </tns1:InputParameters>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>') body from dual
    )
    select t.batch_id
    from fnd_soa_body_piece,
    xmltable( xmlnamespaces(
              'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' as "SOAP-ENC",
              'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "SOAP-ENV",
              'http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/gl/soaprovider/plsql/geas_gl_journal_pkg/geas_get_gl_data/' as "tns1" ),
              '/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Header/SOAP-ENV:Body/tns1:InputParameters/tns1:P_BATCH_TBL/tns1:P_BATCH_TBL_ITEM/tns1:BATCH_ID'
              passing fnd_soa_body_piece.body columns batch_id number(10) PATH 'text()') t
```

Comment: Thank you for the post!! 1. It works only if I don't have the 1st line of xml `<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>` in the xml data How do i handle this? and the second thing is it returns the value in xml format with batch_id tags. How can I just get the data alone?

Comment: This is what the output looks like Example: `<tns1:BATCH_ID xmlns:tns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/gl/soaprovider/plsql/geas_gl_journal_pkg/geas_get_gl_data/">85380</tns1:BATCH_ID><tns1:BATCH_ID xmlns:tns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/gl/soaprovider/plsql/geas_gl_journal_pkg/geas_get_gl_data/">85345</tns1:BATCH_ID>`

Comment: see update in answer.  I have no problem with the XML processing instruction.

Comment: **This worked perfect!!!**. Appreciate your help with this one.  Could you also point me to some basic learning content on XML data querying which would help me?

Comment: The Oracle docs are very good.  Just google "oracle xml db documenation"  As you see, namespaces are a pain!

Comment: Thanks!! again. I would do search. I had Oracle SQL Technical Reference guide which didn't help me much.